Why would people hate Yato if they knew his real name?
In episode 12 season 2 of Noragami, Yato says that if anyone knew his real name (Yaboku), they would hate him.
However, when Hiyori figures it out, no one seems to recognise it, not even the other gods. No one suddenly hates him.
So why would they hate him if they knew his real name?

If it’s relevant, I’ve only watched the anime.
